Grant SQL Server permission to allow a user can access a schema only?
I have many tables in the default dbo schema. I don't want a user to be able to see the dbo tables. I only want the user to see a View. That View is selecting tables from dbo schema. I tried to create a new schema AA, and create the View in this AA schema. Then I run command:
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA ::  AA TO User1
DENY SELECT ON SCHEMA ::  dbo TO User1

But when I login as User1, and select data from AA.View1, the database says:

The SELECT permission was denied on the object dbo.table1, dbo.table2, etc

How can I allow user to select data from the AA.View1 and don't allow them to see any dbo tables?

Why does it matter if they can see they exist..? Smells like an XY Problem.

As for the error, even if a USER has an explicit DENY on a schema, or table, permission chaining can still occur. This suggests that the object on schema AA has a different owner to that of the object on schema dbo; as such the USER must have the SELECT permission GRANTed on the object to be able to SELECT from it (even if that SELECT is inside a VIEW).

This might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/119846/grant-access-only-to-a-schema-in-sql
